# Get single Date For 1 week In Advance If Col=1?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a single date, if a column in my database is set to 1

here is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Appointment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Location` text NOT NULL,
  `Reoccour` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `howfar` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here is my code:

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments");

    while ($Rows = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
    {
        echo "Appointment: {$Rows['Appointment']} <br>";
        echo "Date: {$Rows['Date']} <br>";
        echo "location: {$Rows['Location']} <br>"; 
        if ($Rows['Reoccour'] === 1)
        {
            $NextDate = date('o-m-d', strtotime("+{$Rows['howfar']}"));
            echo "Next Date: {$NextDate}";
        }

    }
```

This does not seem to be adding the next date and showing this in my echo.

What am I doing Wrong? (Apart from using `mysql_*` I have no idea on how to do this task in PDO

Comment: `var_dump($Rows)`.  `Reoccour` is likely to be a string rather than int `1`, and your strict comparison `===` will fail.

Comment: Indeed [from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) _Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments");

    while ($Rows = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
    {
        echo "Appointment: {$Rows['Appointment']} <br>";
        echo "Date: {$Rows['Date']} <br>";
        if ($Rows['Reoccour'] == 0)
        {   
        echo "location: {$Rows['Location']} <br><br>"; 
        }
        if ($Rows['Reoccour'] == 1)
        {
            $NextDate = date('o-m-d', strtotime("+{$Rows['howfar']} weeks"));
            echo "location: {$Rows['Location']} <br>"; 
            echo "Next Date: {$NextDate} <br><br>";
        }

    }
```

You have got two problems.

1) You was looking for a strict comparison with your equals, I changed it to `==` instead of `===`

2) Your second problem was with your `strtotime` Proper usage will be an addition of `weeks` To Your query.. Example:

`echo date('o-m-d', strtotime("+3 weeks"));`

So Your correct syntax will be:
`echo date('o-m-d', strtotime("+{$Rows['howfar']} weeks)); // Notice The Additions of "weeks"`

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` will return an array of strings.
The check:

```
if ($Rows['Reoccour'] === 1){
```

Will only pass if `$Rows['Reoccour']` is both an int and 1 (i.e. `"1" === 1` is false.

Try casting to int or using `==`

Answer (score 0):

Jim's answer is correct. However, you should seriously look into using mysqli_ if you don't want to use PDO. mysql_ is deprecated and has some security issues. However, switching over to mysqli_ is fairly painless and it adds all sorts of new features.

Comment: This is for my own personal localhost home page.. So there is no need to take risks in terms of security

Comment: I still would advise using mysqli_ when possible, since it's best to get into the habit regardless. It's just a better library in general, such as supporting OOP-style database interactions.